# Запятая после оборота "по свидетельству практики"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли в предложении запятая: «По свидетельству практики(,) чаще всего выявление хищений становится возможным в результате комплексного анализа документов»?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, потому что есть вводное словосочетание, указывающее на на источник сообщения (по свидетельству практики). Но предложение какое-то невразумительное, как будто это перевод с иностранного языка (не очень хороший). Может быть лучше так:

**Как показывает практика, чаще всего выявить хищения помогает комплексный анализ документов.**

или

**Практика свидетельствует, что чаще всего выявить хищения можно в ходе комплексного анализа документов.**

Answer (score 0):

Вводными не являются конструкции *"по совету..."*, *"по показанию..."*, *" по постановлению..."*  и подобные. Но, думаю, *"по свидетельству практик"* не из разряда таких конструкций и является вводным.